# ST monad and strictness and sequencing

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz

I'm writing code using Scala and the scalaz library.  I wrote a custom type class to sequence a list of ST monads

```
implicit def richList[A, S](l: List[ST[S, A]]) =
new {
  def sequence: ST[S, List[A]] = 
    l.foldLeft(ST[S, List[A]](Nil))(
      (listST, elemG) => 
        for (list <- listST;
                elem <- elemG
        ) yield elem :: list).map(_.reverse)
}
```

The ST monad calls to ST.map and ST.flatMap are not stack overflow safe.  For a large list, sequencing the list and then calling ST.runST on the ST monad result will result in a stack overflow exception.  I've tried to search the internet for eager analogues of the ST monad, but google search only shows up with autocompletes for the state monad.  The IO monad has a strict version, where chains of map and flatMap don't blow up the stack.  Does something similar exist for the ST monad?

Comment: I don't believe so; in a similar situation I implemented a trampolining `ST` equivalent, which was pretty trivial. Performance was abysmal though so I just gave up using `ST`. YMMV.

Comment: It's not easy doing functional programming in Scala precisely for this reason.